# How to get last inserted identity in Formview Inserted event using VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using VB.net **(FormView and ObjectDataSource)** and Sql Server 2005.

I want to get last inserted **@@identity** in table on **FormView1_ItemInserted**

```
Protected Sub FormView1_ItemInserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewInsertedEventArgs) Handles FormView1.ItemInserted

End Sub
```

My issue is that I want to redirect my FormView to readonly mode after **FormView1_ItemInserted** but for that I need to show the inserted record in readonly mode and that is only possible if I get my last inserted **@@identity**. Can you please let me know what the changes I need to do in my application, Procedures and code to achive this.

Please suggest with example code! using VB.net

Thanks.

Best Regards,
MS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my above problem using below logic

I changed my SQL insert Procedure and  added new Parameter

```
@OrgID int OUTPUT
```

and after insert command

I used

```
SET @OrgID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

RETURN
```

Further in my Application after reconfiguring my ObjectDataSource, I got below parameter

```
    <asp:Parameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" Name="OrgID" Type="Int32" 
        Direction="Output" />
```

in my objectdatasource insert Parameter

I write below code in my ObjectDataSource inserted event.

```
Protected Sub RAOOrganisationDataSource_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles RAOOrganisationDataSource.Inserted
    Dim OrgID As Integer = e.OutputParameters("OrgID")
    Session("OrgID") = OrgID
End Sub
```

And thus I got my latest inserted OrgID in Session.

Cheers!

Please do let me know if there is any errors while using above concept

Answer (score 1):

Actually the easiest way for doing this is by adding the onInserted event to your dataSource which in my case was LinqDatasource.

```
protected void lnqInsert_Inserted(object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
            Session["RecentInsertedClass"] = ((Class)e.Result).ID;
}
```